# localtime and asctime are unsafe, but the safe functions don't have the same parameters

Tags: c++, security, c++11, time, localtime

I'm attempting to create timestamps for my program. On my sister's Mac (using Xcode 4.2) this code works perfectly fine:

```
struct tm * timeInfo;
time_t rawtime;
time (&rawtime);
timeInfo = localtime (&rawtime);
string timestamp(asctime(timeInfo));
```

However, on my PC running Visual Studio 2012 I get errors for localtime and asctime that tell me they are unsafe functions and it recommends using localtime_s and asctime_s. However, the function parameters are different. I've tried researching the functions as best I can, but I can't get it to work.

Any help with getting that to work would be much appreciated.

edit:

```
struct tm * timeInfo;
time_t rawtime;
time (&rawtime);
timeInfo = localtime_s (&rawtime);
string timestamp(asctime_s(timeInfo));
```

Comment: There's a complete example at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Note that those functions are not *standard* C++ and will not work in your MacOS build.

Comment: Linux has localtime_r() (note r not s) which is similar but has the two arguments reversed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason those functions have different parmaters is that the lack of safety is caused by only have a single parameter. In particular, `asctime()` uses a single buffer to return the time. So if you do something like:

```
char *s1 = asctime((time_t)0);   // 1-Jan-1970 00:00:00 or something like that. 
time_t t = time();
char *s2 = asctime(t);
cout << "1970: " << s1 << " now:" << s2 << endl;
```

Then you will not see two different times printed, but the current time printed twice, as both `s1` and `s2` point to the same string.

The same applies to `localtime`, which returns a pointer to `struct tm` - but it's always the same `struct tm`, so you if you do:

```
struct tm* t1 = localtime(0);
struct tm* t2 = localtime(time());
```

you will get the same values in `t1` and `t2` (with the "current" time, not 1970).

So, to fix this problem, [`asctime_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6htak9c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`localtime_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) have an extra parameter that is used to store the data into. `asctime_s` also have a second extra parameter to tell the function how much space there is in the storage buffer, as otherwise, it could overflow that buffer.

Comment: So what are the parameters to asctime_s and localtime_s, and what new variables do I need to meet them?

Comment: See the links provided. There's a pretty good example showing use of both on `asctime_s`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice those were links! Thank you.

Comment: I _almost_ wrote something like "links provided above", but I found it hard to word it correctly, so delete that phrase... Should've left it even if it wasn't so clear.

Comment: Also of relevance: http://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/exploring-c11-part-2-localtime-and-time-again/